# Bottom to top loop deletes every row in excel regardless if the If requirements are met

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I've tried several different variations of the below code to try to find a method that may work. My last iteration left me at:

```
Dim D As Range
Dim x As Integer, c As Long, lre As Long
c = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

lre = Sheets("Exception Report").Cells(Sheets("ExceptionReport").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Range("D2:D" & lre).TextToColumns
Range("F2:F" & lre).TextToColumns

For x = c To 2 Step -1
    If -0.1 < CDbl((Cells(x, "D").Value) - (Cells(x, "E").Value)) < 0.1 And -0.1 < CDbl((Cells(x, "F").Value) - (Cells(x, "G").Value)) < 0.1 Then
    Cells(x, 1).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next
```

The code in this part look at two pairs of cells, and I subtract one from the other in order to look at the difference. If it is within the range above (The -0.1 < code < 0.1) then it is to be deleted, basically leaving certain outliers. The text to columns part turns some of the data (which is stored as text) into number datatype so I can work with it for this purpose.

The problem I have been facing is that no matter the numbers used, it evaluates as true which then deletes the entire row, leaving the report blank, even though I know that there are rows which do not meet the criteria.

I've run out of ideas and my novice experience with excel has left me unable to debug this. Any help/comments/ideas?

Comment: Is it a typo in the post here on SO? You have `Sheets("Exception Report")` and also `Sheets("ExceptionReport")` in the `lre = ... ` line.  This could certainly cause confusion in VBA.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I had caught that after I already posted this but there is the answer below! Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have multiple comparisons like  `a < b < c`, you need to use `a < b And b < c`.

I am not exactly sure what happens but one of the `<`s is evaluated first and the result (`True` or `False`) is then compared to the last number which mixes things up.

Edit: the first `<` seems to be evaluated first, giving `True` or `False` since `True` is evaluated as `-1` and `False` as `0` when being cast as `Double`, you always get `True` when checking `<0.1`.

Comment: Beat me to it - was just trying to work out the logic of it.

Comment: Thank you! I assumed I could work multiple into one like that, without really questioning it. I made 4 statement strung together with     and and it ended up working just as I needed it. Thanks again.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook I have to admit that I got once again confused because `True` = -1 (although it makes sense of course)

Comment: @SsaSnakebite you could also use the absolute value (`Abs`) to slim down the code.