# Looping through the Rows from LAST

Tags: excel, vba, loops

Im Totally new to VBA.. Im trying to Loop through a column's rows from last filled row. I have googled about this but I could find code that iterates only from the top.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38314573/running-a-loop-from-bottom-to-top), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38311477/bottom-to-top-loop-deletes-every-row-in-excel-regardless-if-the-if-requirements), [here too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24358183/reverse-order-of-for-each-loop).... and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to populate a variable with the last row and use `Step -1`, which indicates the direction

```
Sub loopbackwards()
Dim i As Long, LRow As Long

With Workbooks(REF).Sheets(REF)

    LRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = LRow to 2 Step -1 'i represents the row nr.
        Debug.Print i
        'or do stuff
    Next i

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Tim you forgot to declare **i**. To avoid this use **Option Explicit**

Comment: I "forgot" to declare LRow too didn't I?

Comment: yes. i forgot to mention that. Also have in mind that both **REFs** in your code should surrounded by double quotes

Comment: I'm absolutely not going to double qoute REF. Users need to reference to their own wb/ws. Inexperienced users are less likely to think double quoted REFs need editing.

Comment: I agree with the `Users need to reference to their own wb/ws` but what you wrote has no sense. If he is going to reference,  he will use `With ws`, who would reference a sheet name if it doesn't come from another procedure? Even then, you would set the worksheet object, not a string.

Comment: I've used REF in my answers for ages, never has anyone had issues with it. I understand the both of you, but bit of a useless discussion this :)

Comment: Every question is different & unique. the OP starts with *Im Totally new to VBA.*